# Locked of Server, how to run sudo passwordless

Tags: linux, permissions, sudo, amazon-linux, amazon-linux-2

Here is the issue

- Created a new server with Amazon Linux 2
- Removed ssh-key from default root user (ec2-user)
- Created two new accounts with sudo access without a password

Now I got locked out of the root access in this server, anytime I run a 'sudo' command the OS is asking for a password. But during user creation I never set any password. Additionally, `passwd` is asking for the current password.

Anything I can do, except start again?

Comment: You can shut the instance down, attach and mount its root volume on a different instance, and reset the passwords. If you aren't far along with the instance, its easier to delete it and start over.

Comment: ended reseting the server since it was a fresh new one anyhow with no data

Comment: You can't have a root user without a password on any modern Linux once you removed the SSH key you didn't replace the password an account with a null and as a result you could no longer get In. It may also be that local passwords for disabled and once you removed the SSH key you lost it. Doing this doesn't seem to be any type of good practice.